# How do I import this complicated data constructor, and nothing more?

Tags: haskell

I'd like to import the `Vec3D` data constructor from the Vec package, the `Data.Vec.Packed` module. Obviously, I can

```
import Data.Vec.Packed
```

and be done with things, but that's not what I want to do, because that adds extra stuff to what's currently in scope.

The `Vec3D` data constructor is declared like this in the `Data.Vec.Packed` module:

```
instance PackedVec (Vec3 Double) where
  data Packed (Vec3 Double) = Vec3D {-#UNPACK#-} !Double {-#UNPACK#-} !Double {-#UNPACK#-} !Double
...
```

I tried this, but it didn't compile:

```
import Data.Vec.Packed (Packed (Vec3 Double)(..))
```

How can I import just the `Vec3D` data constructor?

FYI, if you import the module in ghci:

```
* Data.Vec> :info  Vec3D
data instance Packed (Vec3 Double)
  = Vec3D {-# UNPACK #-}Double
          {-# UNPACK #-}Double
          {-# UNPACK #-}Double
    -- Defined in ‘Data.Vec.Packed’

type Vec3D = Packed (Vec3 Double)   -- Defined in ‘Data.Vec.Packed’
```

Comment: Unfortunately Haskell doesn't provide any way to only import a specific *type class instance*. Importing anything from a module imports **all** instances defined there. So even doing `import Data.Vec.Packed()` which explicitly says to import nothing in scope will still import all class instances defined in that module.

Comment: You could of course circumvent the problem with [`import Linear.V3(V3(..))`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.5/docs/Linear-V3.html), though I'd see why you might want to avoid the heavy dependencies of `linear`.

Comment: @Bakuriu, using `import Data.Vec.Packed ()` does not import the `Vec3D` data constructor. I still don't understand how to import the data constructor without importing the whole module.

Answer (score 0):

To bundle the constructor with the family import, you can write

`import Data.Vec.Packed (Packed(Vec3D))`

Testing this in GHCi with `:info Vec3D` shows

```
data instance Packed (Data.Vec.Base.Vec3 Double)
  = Vec3D {-# UNPACK #-}Double
          {-# UNPACK #-}Double
          {-# UNPACK #-}Double
        -- Defined in ‘Data.Vec.Packed’
```